# Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I am trying to read the drone imagery (20 cm) with rasterio library but getting an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manap/PycharmProjects/rio-tiler/multi.py", line 33, in <module>
    with COGReader(r"/home/manap/munich_1.tif") as image:
  File "<attrs generated init rio_tiler.io.cogeo.COGReader>", line 14, in __init__
  File "/home/manap/PycharmProjects/rio-tiler/rio_tiler/io/cogeo.py", line 107, in __attrs_post_init__
    self._set_zooms()
  File "/home/manap/PycharmProjects/rio-tiler/rio_tiler/io/cogeo.py", line 155, in _set_zooms
    minzoom, maxzoom = self.get_zooms()
  File "/home/manap/PycharmProjects/rio-tiler/rio_tiler/io/cogeo.py", line 137, in get_zooms
    *self.dataset.bounds,
  File "/home/manap/PycharmProjects/rio-tiler/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/env.py", line 387, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/manap/PycharmProjects/rio-tiler/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/warp.py", line 509, in calculate_default_transform
    src_crs, dst_crs, width, height, left, bottom, right, top, gcps, rpcs, **kwargs
  File "rasterio/_warp.pyx", line 697, in rasterio._warp._calculate_default_transform
  File "rasterio/_warp.pyx", line 679, in rasterio._warp._calculate_default_transform
  File "rasterio/_err.pyx", line 192, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_int
rasterio._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError: Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my code:

```
from rio_tiler.io import COGReader
import rio_tiler
with COGReader(r"/home/manap/munich_1.tif") as image:
    print(image)
```

the image can be downloaded from https://eoxplore-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/chiefscienceofficer_eoxplore_onmicrosoft_com/EpsWYilRNh5Eld4cU5p_fe4BVQX7FBoRMZXnD89qKba80w

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find an `munich_1.tif`. Instead I found a image `DOP_20/4468260_5331209.tif` in your repository. The image has a dimension of `16425x12760`:

```
gdalinfo 4468260_5331209.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 4468260_5331209.tif
       4468260_5331209.tif.ovr
Size is 16425, 12760
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4",
    GEOGCS["DHDN",
        DATUM["Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
            SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
            TOWGS84[598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6314"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4314"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",12],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",4500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","31468"]]
Origin = (4468259.984000000171363,5333761.273000000044703)
Pixel Size = (0.200000000000000,-0.200000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_COPYRIGHT=*************************
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=07.05.2018 00:00:00
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=3 (pixels/cm)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=*************************
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=250
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=250
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 4468259.984, 5333761.273) ( 11d34'24.42"E, 48d 8'31.22"N)
Lower Left  ( 4468259.984, 5331209.273) ( 11d34'25.11"E, 48d 7' 8.59"N)
Upper Right ( 4471544.984, 5333761.273) ( 11d37' 3.35"E, 48d 8'31.78"N)
Lower Right ( 4471544.984, 5331209.273) ( 11d37' 3.96"E, 48d 7' 9.15"N)
Center      ( 4469902.484, 5332485.273) ( 11d35'44.21"E, 48d 7'50.19"N)
Band 1 Block=16425x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 8213x6380, 4107x3190, 2054x1595, 1027x798, 514x399, 257x200
Band 2 Block=16425x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 8213x6380, 4107x3190, 2054x1595, 1027x798, 514x399, 257x200
Band 3 Block=16425x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 8213x6380, 4107x3190, 2054x1595, 1027x798, 514x399, 257x200
```

According to the code in [`warp.py`](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/rio/warp.py) the operation is limited to a image size of 100000x100000 cells.

```
"""$ rio warp"""
    
...

# Improper usage of rio-warp can lead to accidental creation of
# extremely large datasets. We'll put a hard limit on the size of
# datasets and raise a usage error if the limits are exceeded.
MAX_OUTPUT_WIDTH = 100000
MAX_OUTPUT_HEIGHT = 100000
```

So the source dimension `16425x12760` should not be an issue. When I install the environment on Ubuntu 18.04 - 64 bit with

```
  pip3 install rasterio 
  pip3 install rio_tiler
```

,download the DOP_20 image and call my the example code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from rio_tiler.io import COGReader
import rio_tiler

FILE='DOP_20/4468260_5331209.tif'

with COGReader(FILE) as image:
    print(image)
```

I get no error during the image open step.

```
COGReader(\
   bounds=(11.572063386087754, 48.11813315397459, \
           11.61637335456606, 48.14123922531762), \
   filepath='DOP_20/4468260_5331209.tif', \
   dataset=<open DatasetReader \ 
   name='DOP_20/4468260_5331209.tif' \
   mode='r'>, \
   tms=<TileMatrixSet \
        title='Google Maps Compatible for the World' \
        identifier='WebMercatorQuad'>, \
   minzoom=13, \
   maxzoom=19, \
   colormap={}, \
   nodata=None, \
   unscale=None, \
   resampling_method=None, \
   vrt_options=None, \
   post_process=None, \
   _kwargs={})
```

IMO you try to transform the image, with some code not explained in your question. Can you provide this code and the parameter set for the `warp` call.

### Review

I assume you have copied the image `DOP_20/4468260_5331209.tif` else where and renamed it.  The image has some more metadata in the directory DOP_20:

```
4468260_5331209.tfw
4468260_5331209.tif
4468260_5331209.tif.ovr
4468260_5331209.txt
4468260_5331209.wld
```

I've read the data from the original DOP_20 directory and got no error, while your copy make some trouble with the rastreio. To make the Geotif portable and self contained with the overview images, you could use the commands `gdal_translate` and `gdaladdo`:

```
gdal_translate -co BIGTIF=YES      \
               -co COMPRESS=LZW    \
               -co SPARSE_OK=TRUE  \
               -co TILED=yes       \
               -co BLOCKXSIZE=1024 \
               -co BLOCKYSIZE=1024 \
               4468260_5331209.tif \ 
               4468260_5331209.blocks.tif 

gdaladdo -r lanczos 4468260_5331209.blocks.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

When I read your script right, then you try to split the image into 256x256 tiles driven by your text file. The script triggers for all entries exceptions the exception TileOutsideBounds.

```
~/Source/IfGDV-GSE/Test-Tile/tiling$ ./script.py
278707
181023
EXCEPT: TileOutsideBounds
...
```

Here is your adopted script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from rio_tiler.io import COGReader
import os
import rio_tiler
import pandas as pd
import time
from PIL import Image

# Preparation -------------------------------------
# PRJ_DIR=$HOME/Source/IfGDV-GSE/Test-Tile
# mv tiling-20211210T084355Z-001.zip $PRJ_DIR
# unzip $PRJ_DIR/tiling-20211210T084355Z-001.zip
# cd $PRJ_DIR/tiling
# mkdir result
# gdal_translate -co BIGTIF=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co SPARSE_OK=TRUE -co TILED=yes -co BLOCKXSIZE=1024 -co BLOCKYSIZE=1024 munich_20cm.tif munich_20cm.blocks.tif
# gdaladdo -r lanczos munich_20cm.blocks.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64
# mv script.txt script.py
# dos2unix  script.py
# chmod 755 script.py
# emacs -nw script.py
# --------------------------------------------------
# add shebang #!/usr/bin/env python3
# add some variables

HOME        = os.environ.get('HOME')
WORK_DIR    = HOME+'/Source/IfGDV-GSE/Test-Tile/tiling/'
DST_PATH    = WORK_DIR+'result/'
SRC_LIST    = WORK_DIR+'new_munich.txt'
# SRC_IMAGE = WORK_DIR+'munich_20cm.tif'
SRC_IMAGE   = WORK_DIR+'munich_20cm.blocks.tif'

SRC_FILE   = open(SRC_LIST, 'r')
SRC_POINTS = SRC_FILE.readlines()

image =  COGReader(SRC_IMAGE)

number = len(SRC_POINTS)
for coordinates in SRC_POINTS:

    x = int(coordinates.split(',')[0])
    y = int(coordinates.split(',')[1])
    print(x)
    print(y)
    z = 19
    number -= 1
    try:
        filename = DST_PATH + str(x) +'/' + str(y) + '.png'
        print(filename)
        img = image.tile(x, y, z, tilesize=256)
        buff = img.render()

        # check for existence of the direction
        x_direction = os.path.join(DST_PATH, str(x))
        if os.path.exists(x_direction) == False:
            os.mkdir(x_direction)
        with open(os.path.join(x_direction, str(y) + '.png'), "wb") as f:
            f.write(buff)

        #os.remove(filename)

    except rio_tiler.errors.TileOutsideBounds:
        print("EXCEPT: TileOutsideBounds")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am trying only to read the image but I am getting an error. Have you done some edits with the image or code?

Comment: I've installed `rasterio` and and `rio_tiler` via `pip3` on Ubuntu 18.04, and changed as mentioned above the file name because `munich_1.tif` was not in the `DOP_20` directory. Where does your `munich_1.tif` comes from? Is it the same files a   `DOP_20/4468260_5331209.tif` or is it a larger file not in provided `DOP_20` remote directory?

Comment: yes you are using correct image, i just changed the name

Comment: And the size is the same? Can you check with `gdalinfo munich_1.tif`.

Comment: If I send x,y,z coordinates as a txt file can you please tile it for me? the script is read, you just need to configure directories.

Comment: I am getting same error again and again

Comment: I yes I can tile it ...

Comment: i have uploaded files to here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zneVCdlIIAEjyQvnKZjCHCs9MMQMxUTu?usp=sharing

Comment: OK I got the problem ..review of the answer

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: what if you try to use an initial image which is DOP_20/4468260_5331209.tif

Comment: The adopted script is in the answer and creates files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132216/discussion-between-huckfinn-and-manap-shymyr).

Comment: i am in the chat room