# How to define origin and extent for Raster Images and getting it work properly in gdal2tiles

Tags: qgis, extents, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

I'm trying to generate Raster Tiles for my Nasa's Black Marble which has the dimension of 86,400 x 43,200 that I combined out of all the 8 images.

[image]

I've been known about `gdal2tiles`. So basically, I directly tried to pass it in **gdal2tiles** as raster which it did generate tiles but it was not seemless as OSM which use epsg:3857 and had gaps from three side.

Earlier I didn't assigned any projection to it. I tried doing the same with Nasa's low ress [GeoTiFF](https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/144000/144898/BlackMarble_2016_3km_geo.tif) and passed it in gdal2tiles with Mercator profile and it worked seamlessly.  Then I check its extent and properties which is highlighted below and ranges perfectly.

[image]

As compared to mine when I assigned the projection to `epsg:4326` the extend were displayed in pixels instead of latitude and longitude

[image]

Even then I tried to match it with what Nasa's came with but weirdly it generates equirectangle image of only blank black color.

[image]

I also tried to pass it in `gdal2tiles` after assigning epsg:4326 which extent displayed in pixel and got this error - [Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/418425/213228). But then I tried `gdal_translate` followed with again `gdal2tiles` and got  my tiles placed near Africa. `gdal_warp` gave an error of Lat and Long not valid when trying it morph it in **epsg:3857**.

[image]

What I'm assuming is my main issue is with defining the extent and origin. Any idea on how to fix this issue without changing anything in the map? I've been scratching my head from last two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad, I had to change the extent to -180 to 180, -90 to 90 degree while exporting the image or I should have just used the [world file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBCWkVtQksA)

The original extent was defined in pixel values rather than actual coordinates.